# Как поместить сторонний зашифрованный файл в docx так, чтобы ворд мог открыться

Tags: c#, ms-word

Если открыть файл docx через 7zip, то можно увитеть вот такой контент:
[image: Открытый файл docx]

Мне нужно добавить сюда свой запароленый файл (config.xml к примеру) с конфигурацией для моего приложения (добавляю через Ionic.Zip). Когда я пытаюсь это сделать ворд также читает этот файл и говорит что архив повреждён и нечитабелен.

[image: Ошибка]

Если пароль не ставить, то всё работает как должно. А мне нужно, чтобы файл был запаролен.

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: первый вопрос - а для чего? Почему нельзя ложить файл рядом с .docx, почему именно внутрь?

Comment: @iikuzmychov Мне нужно выгружать это одним файлом. Чтобы был один docx, но открывался в моём приложении как мне надо.
UPD: Я хочу записывать туда айди копии программы, которая этот файл обработала и чтобы прочитать я мог эти данные уже на своём сервере.

Comment: если вам нужно просто записать id, запишите его в метаданные файла. Что то, что то можно вручную при желании поменять, но это гораздо проще записать в метаданные

Comment: @iikuzmychov я не хочу чтобы эти данные можно было менять. Мне нужно, чтобы я мог понять как был записан или обработан файл так, чтобы нельзя было подделать эту подпись.

Comment: если вы положите те же самые данные внутрь .docx их можно будет ровно также поменять

Comment: @iikuzmychov удалить и записать новые. Или для того чтобы это сделать будет недостаточно открыть notepad.exe и поменять 123 на 124. (потому что будет установлен пароль) У меня нет цели удивить программиста, мне просто нужно убрать "возможность обхода ArchiCAD'а (или lumion, не помню уже)", когда достаточно просто удалить файл license.reg и запустить батником exe`шку.

Comment: Я хотя бы увижу что файл удалялся и ставился новый на его место, имеется в виду.

Comment: как вы увидите что файл редактировался? по дате? это те же самые метаданные

Comment: `Если пароль не ставить, то всё работает как должно` - ну засунь свой запароленный файл внутрь незапароленного архива.  ворд не будет эти твои матрёшки открывать до бесконечности.  (такой трюк срабатывает, чтобы отправить гуглопочтой запароленный архив.)

Comment: @iikuzmychov Я хотел сериализовать модель с информацией о файле в xml и закидывать внутрь. Там внутри я хотел написать алгоритм шифрования данных, который шифровал бы ключ. Если на сервере ключ расшифруется и будет сопоставлен с базой данных, то я бы сказал, что файл был собран моим приложением. Если целостность нарушена или данные не декриптятся, то, вероятно, файл меняли.